# Print the difference between two time stamps in oracle sql Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to print the difference in the time stamps for CREATETS and MODIFYTS, How do I do it in Oracle Sql Developer?[image: table]

Comment: What's wrong with `modifyts - createts`. See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#i48042

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiply difference with 24*60*60 to get the difference in seconds. example-  (modifyts - createts)*24*60*60.

Comment: RanaThanks for your help, One small question

Comment: if I want to get a list of records where modifyts - createts is equal to 2 days 10 hrs 30 minutes, how to write the sql statement for it?

Comment: Select * from table_name where modifyts - createts=''?

Comment: SELECT *
  FROM timestamps
 WHERE modifyts - createts = INTERVAL '2 10:30:00' DAY TO SECOND;

Comment: Hi Nagaraj, You can just convert them to seconds like- for day to second multiply by 86400 (ie. 60*60*24), for hour to second multiply by 60*60, for minutes multiply by 60 and add them. For your example- (2*86400 + 10*60*60 + 30*60)

Comment: Infact you can have some range too.